# Error callback in amazon-ivs-web-broadcast

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-ivs

I am using amazon-ivs-web-broadcast.js(https://web-broadcast.live-video.net/1.6.0/amazon-ivs-web-broadcast.js) to record meetings,
To handle error i added try and catch blocks to all give fucnction like  `IVSBroadcastClient?.create`

Apart from this is there any callback which is triggered on error for the scenarios like broadcast stream failure

In other words is there any way to detect any failure in `IVSBroadcastClient` during streaming

```
async createBroadcast(resolution: string,channelType: string) {
        if(typeof window != "undefined" && window.IVSBroadcastClient){
            try {
                const streamConfig = this.getConfigFromResolution(resolution,channelType);
                this.broadcastClient = window.IVSBroadcastClient?.create({
                    streamConfig: streamConfig
                  })
                
                return this.broadcastClient;
              } catch (error) {
                this.errorMsg = IVSErrorMsg.error_creating_stream
              }
        }
    }
```